# Given a prime factorization of a number, find all of its other factorizations (not factors)

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Is there an algorithm to determine all distinct factorizations of a number, if both the number and its prime factorization are known?

Example

n = 64

f = 2^6

The factors are:

1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64

I am not asking for the above. Instead, is there a method to find the following:

- 1 * 64
- 2 * 32
- 2 * 2 * 16
- 2 * 2 * 2 * 8
- 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 4
- 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2
- 4 * 16
- 4 * 2 * 8
- 4 * 4 * 4
- 8 * 8

The above example has one distinct prime factor, but I would like a solution generalized to n distinct prime factors.

Answer (score 1):

Recursively: for each factor $f$ of your number $n$, prepend $(f)$ to all factorizations of $n/f$ where all factors $\ge f$...

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Adrian Keister in a comment, what follows doesn't answer the question asked. However, because this answers what is probably an often asked related question, I'll leave it up, at least unless I start getting killed with downvotes $\ldots$

Let $N$ be a positive integer with prime factorization

$$ N \; = \; p_{1}^{n_1} p_{2}^{n_2} p_{3}^{n_3} \cdots p_{k}^{n_k}$$

Then, including $1$ and $N,$ there are

$$ (n_1 + 1)(n_2 + 1)(n_3 + 1) \cdots (n_k + 1) $$

many factors of $N,$ and each factor has the form

$$ p_{1}^{{\alpha}_1} p_{2}^{{\alpha}_2} p_{3}^{{\alpha}_3} \cdots p_{k}^{{\alpha}_k}$$

where each $\alpha_i$ belongs to $\{0,\,1,\,2,\,3,\, \ldots,\,n_i \}.$

**Example:** Let $N = 45000 = 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^4.$ Then the $(3+1)(2+1)(4+1) = 60$ many factors are

$$ 2^0 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^0 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^0 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^0 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^3 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^0 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^4 $$

$$ 2^0 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^0 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^0 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^0 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^3 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^0 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^4 $$

$$ 2^0 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^0 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^0 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^0 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^3 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^0 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^4 $$

$$ 2^1 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^1 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^1 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^1 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^3 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^1 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^4 $$

$$ 2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^3 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^4 $$

$$ 2^1 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^1 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^1 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^1 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^3 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^1 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^4 $$

$$ 2^2 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^2 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^2 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^2 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^3 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^2 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^4 $$

$$ 2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^3 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^4 $$

$$ 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^3 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^4 $$

$$ 2^3 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^3 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^3 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^3 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^3 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^3 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^4 $$

$$ 2^3 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^3 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^3 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^3 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^3 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^3 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^4 $$

$$ 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^3 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^4 $$

In this example, note that the exponents on $2$ come from $\{0,\,1,\,2,\,3\}$ and the exponents on $3$ come from $\{0,\,1,\,2\}$ and the exponents on $5$ come from $\{0,\,1,\,2,\,3,\, 4\}.$ One way to organize the possible choices of choosing exponents is the same way you would when trying all combinations for a [combination lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination_lock) whose unlocking sequence of digits you've forgotten or lost, sometime I've had to do at least twice, and not for fun, when I was a child.

Comment: This will find all the factors. But the OP wants all the factorizations of the full number. The tricky part, it seems to me, is that you have a varying number of numbers in all possible factorizations. It's kind of like a partition of the prime factorization: how many ways can you "clump" the numbers in the prime factorization into different numbers?

Comment: @Adrian Keister: I just reread the question more carefully, and I see your point. I'll add a disclaimer, but after all that formatting I'm not really up to trying to do what appears to be asked.

Comment: Yes @AdrianKeister, exactly. I am familiar with Dave's answer; I have notes from this lecture in college. This does give me the idea of considering how to split and permute the exponents to which each prime is raised to generate all factorizations.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro: I think you could adapt your answer. I found a C++ answer on SO, but it was recursive, and didn't seem to take advantage of knowing the prime factorization.

Comment: Maybe adapt a partition-finding algorithm?

Comment: *partition-finding algorithm* --- I know pretty much no programming, but I can see why "partition" seems to be relevant. For each of the factors I gave of $45000$ we can obtain a "$2$-factors factorization" of $45000,$ but we also want to include all "$3$-factors factorizations of $45000$", all "$4$-factors factorizations of $45000$", etc. (I'm assuming order of factors doesn't matter. Besides, if the order mattered, it's a simple matter to include the permutations of each possibility.)

Comment: Exactly. The max number of numbers in a factorization would be the sum of the exponents in the prime factorization, right? By the way, while I'm decent at programming, it's not as though I have some answer up my sleeve, either. Just talking this out...

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKeister, I will look into such an algorithm. I am considering a slightly modified approach now. I'll add it as an edit to the body of the question.

Comment: Actually, I believe that approach is different enough that it merits its own question.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all divisors $d$ of $n$ and then recursively list all factorizations of $n/d$ where every factor is at most $d$. If you want to know how to implement this efficiently, I can code something in c++.

Comment: That would be cool. I am looking to implement it in Go, but C++ (or pseudocode) would be good too.

Comment: Try this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932357/find-all-factorizations-of-a-number